# Overriding a plugin's renderer?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.2

I've been trying to figure out how to do this, but nothing seems to really work:

I want to override the results/pagination renderers from ZOOFilter which I know is in `/plugins/system/zoofilter/zoofilter/layouts/{search,_pagination}.php`, however it only appears that I can override templates?

The way that ZOOFilter is currently built is that it does not have any `/tmpl` directories in any of the plugin's locations within my installation, and obviously overwriting the plugin's code itself is more or less out of the question.

Comment: As this question is about Joomla extensions, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Done. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/overriding-a-plugins-renderer